# Anaconda installed but Python in Visual Studio does not recognize Numpy

Tags: windows, visual-studio, python-2.7, anaconda

I installed Anacoda and then Visual studio on windows 7 as explained in :
https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/ide_integration#python-tools-for-visual-studio-ptvs
but my visual studio does not recognize Numpy and some other modules...
What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the list of available python packages from the solutions explorer? If already inside a project, you can right-click on the Python2.7(global environment) and try 'install package' and enter 'numpy' and install from 'pip' or 'conda'. (See ImageLink at the end of this paragraph). This should install numpy. [ImageLink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Xijl.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add to this PATH in the enviroment variables:

yourAnacondaPath/Library/bin

it worked for me.